# Installshield Extension Condition issues

Tags: installshield

Im trying to create an Extension condition in C# based on the Installshield article http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/SteExtCondAuthor.htm#buildingconditionalstatements_384870052_1039129

but this is referencing c++. Anyone do this in c# or have some examples in c#

Answer (score 0):

Conditions may be evaluated multiple times, so we suggest keeping extension conditions fast and implemented in C++. And as of yet there is no built-in C# support for extension conditions. That said, I've seen a utility that creates an unmanaged entry point that can run managed code, and you may be able to use that wrapper. (Unfortunately I do not remember what it is called.)

Once you have your managed code up and running, you just need to communicate back with the Suite. Do this by declaring the ISuiteExtension interface, and use the IDispatch parameter to your method as such, just like in the C++ example. Reference the topic [Working with a Managed-Code Action in a Suite/Advanced UI Installation](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/SteActionManagedCd.htm) for the C# declaration of ISuiteExtension, and some samples of how to write code using it.

Comment: So i currently use the managed code approach with the ISuiteExtension interface for custom actions but that same code cant be called from an Extension condition, i assume because im not also using the "IDispatch" parameter?

Comment: The actions know how to spin up the CLR and call managed code, but conditions only know how to load unmanaged C/C++ right now.

Comment: So i pretty much have no choice but c/c++?